# How do you disable Cassandra's Python Driver logs?

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm using Cassandra's Python driver (3.16).

Cassandra spits out a ton of non-essential WARNING logs that clog up my terminal.  How can I disable them in my python project?

Answer (score 3):

Python logging is by modules or classes as we call it outside python.

You can disable logging on a module level using this command:

```
logging.getLogger('cassandra').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

This will set the logging level to ERROR and will not print logs with level below ERROR.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about warnings, and not just warn logs, the Python driver uses the built-in warning facilities for this. They usually indicate a misuse, or using a feature that will soon be deprecated, so it's good to heed them.

If you still need to suppress, try using the `ignore` filter described in the Python library docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter

Answer (score 0):

Python driver uses standard Python module [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), so you can set corresponding [logging level](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels), such as, `ERROR` or `CRITICAL`.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel('ERROR')
```

P.S. But usually, the `WARNING` shouldn't be printed without reason, so I would recommend to investigate specific messages.

Answer (score 0):

If this is [DataStax' Python driver for Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver), then it is using Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and organizing the loggers and handlers per module (see [source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adatastax%2Fpython-driver+logging+language%3APython+path%3A%2F%5Ecassandra%5C%2F%2F&type=code)).

You can print all the available loggers by:

```
import logging

for handler, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
    if handler.startswith("cassandra"):
        print(f"{handler=} {logger=}")
```

```
handler='cassandra' logger=<Logger cassandra (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.auth' logger=<Logger cassandra.auth (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.util' logger=<Logger cassandra.util (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.cqltypes' logger=<Logger cassandra.cqltypes (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.policies' logger=<Logger cassandra.policies (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.protocol' logger=<Logger cassandra.protocol (DEBUG)>
handler='cassandra.connection' logger=<Logger cassandra.connection (DEBUG)>
...
```

You can configure specific loggers.
For example just turning off `"cassandra.cluster"` debug logs:

```
import logging

c_conn_logger = logging.getLogger("cassandra.connection")
c_conn_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

You can also just let it propagate to your root logger then customize it there instead:

```
import logging

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
c_conn_logger = logging.getLogger("cassandra.connection")
c_conn_logger.propagate = True
```

You can also just turn all the debug logs "off":

```
import logging

for handler, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
    if handler.startswith("cassandra") and not isinstance(logger, logging.PlaceHolder):
        logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  # or CRITICAL
        logger.propagate = False
```